# OpenMP parallelization of nested loops

Tags: c, openmp, nested-loops

I am practicing for an exam and I would like to know how to solve correctly the following C program using OpenMP.

The following program searches the biggest element in positions i..N-1 from vector
values[] and the results are stored in a second vector (maxs[]). Parallelize this program
by adding the appropriate OpenMP statements. Provide two different solutions:

1. One based on the parallelization of the outer loop
2. The second one based on the parallelization ofthe inner loop.

Add variables and changes in the code in order to achieve a more efficient solution (the score of the exercise will take into account this).

Provide explanations that describe how the program is parallelized and how threads are
going to collaborate in each case, assuming the application will run with T threads
(T<<N).

```
int values[N], sums[N]
int i , j, s;

for (i = 0; i < N ; i ++) {
    s = values[i];

    for (j = i+1; j < N ; j ++)
        if (s < values[j])
            s = value[j];
 
    maxs[i] = s;
}
```

For the first case, the answer I would provide is the following:

```
int values[N], sums[N]
int s;

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1)
for (int i = 0; i < N ; i ++) {
    s = values[i];

    for (int j = i+1; j < N ; j ++)
        if (s < values[j])
             s = value[j];

    maxs[i] = s;
}
```

I am simply parallelizing the outer loop, using a dynamic schedule. Thus, every time a thread is available it will handle an iteration. I do not use an ordered clause because the order of the execution does not really matter in this case. Moreover, I have not used the collapse(2) clause because the statement specifies that I only need to parallelize the outer loop (not the inner loop).

In the second scenario, I would answer the following:

```
int values[N], sums[N]
int s;

for (int i = 0; i < N ; i ++) {
    s = values[i];
    
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1)
    for (int j = i+1; j < N ; j ++)
        if (s < values[j])
             s = value[j];

    maxs[i] = s;
}
```

How could I optimize the code in order to obtain the highest grade possible?

Thanks! :)

Comment: In the first case, what do you think should be the status of variable `s` in term of storage? `shared`, `private`, `firstprivate`, `lastprivate`, `reduction(xx:)`? And same for the second case. The scheduling aspect is secondary.

Comment: @Gilles Oh, yeah! You are absolutely right. I would add the clause private(s), otherwise many threads will generate conflicts because they will read and modify the same variable.

Comment: You do that in case 1? Case 2? Both?

Comment: @Gilles I may be wrong. But I would use private(s) for the first scenario and firstprivate(s) for the second scenario.

Comment: Think more, you can do it

Comment: @Gilles I am confident about the first scenario. In the second case, I can not use private or firstprivate because, when exiting the inner loop, the value of s is going to be the original one (the one before entering the inner loop). 

Lastprivate and reduction will also lead to wrong answers. Thus, I would use shared(s).

But if I use shared(s) I think I will also have some issues, because multiple threads will be reading and modifying the same variable.

Comment: Correct for the first scenario. Think of what the purpose of `s` is for the second one

Comment: @Gilles The variable "s" is used to keep track of the maximum value encountered while iterating over the values array.

Comment: ohhhh I see... hahahahah

Comment: I need to add the clause reduction(max: s)

Comment: But, following this explanation, why should I not also use reduction(max: s) in the first scenario?

Comment: In your first scenario the content of `s` is not needed outside of the parallel part, it is needed only within an iteration. In the second scenario the content of `s` is needed outside of the parallel part. To make this clearer, there is an alternative solution to the `private` clause in the first scenario.

Comment: @PierU Okay I see. Let's say that I want to parallelize both loops. In this case, should I use the reduction() clause?

Comment: Depends on how you are effectively parallelizing both loops.

Comment: Well, I would add the following pragma directive:
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) schedule(dynamic, 1) reduction(max: s)

Comment: Try it, and see what happens

Comment: I see the problem. I can not use collapse(2) since they are not completly perfect nested loops. Meaning that the inner loop is not right before the outer loop.

Comment: Whoever wrote this exam question has fallen behind the times. If you run the outer loop backwards, your recognize this as a scan operation which is part of OpenMP version 5.  So part 3 of your exercise should have been: implement using using `omp scan`. That will run pretty much at the speed of a single reduction loop.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I will notify the teacher. hahahaha :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is not strictly following your instructions but maybe it will benefit someone:

```
data:  1  1  4  3  3  2  1  4  4  5  2  3  5  1  1  3  4  1  2  1  3
maxs:  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  4  4  4  4  3  3  3  3
```

This was generated (minus boilerplate and printing) by:

```
  int partial_max;
  partial_max=0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(inscan,max:partial_max)
  for ( int i=values.size()-1; i>=0; i-- ) {
    auto v = values[i];
    partial_max = std::max( partial_max, v );
#   pragma omp scan inclusive(partial_max)
    max_so_far[i] = partial_max;
  }
```

Note that `scan` is fairly new and not every compiler may support it. I'm using gcc12.